# How is the kernel of a matrix also the image?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $A =\begin{pmatrix}2&-1&3&3\\ 0&0&2&2\\ 4&-2&5&5\end{pmatrix}$ and its kernel, given by the span of $(1, 2, 0, 0)^{\top}$ and  $(0, 0, 1, -1)^{\top}$

Row reducing the matrix gives $\begin{pmatrix}2&-1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&1\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

I just take the first and third rows of $A$ to be a basis for the image. However, a suggested solution I saw was "the elements of the kernel are the basis of Im$(A)$" and I was very confused about what this could mean or imply. Any suggestions?

Comment: They probably meant that $\ker(A) = \text{im}(A^T)$.

Comment: I think it's clearly false in general. For example, viewing $A$ as a homomorphism $\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^3$, its kernel and image are not even in the same set.

Comment: even if they meant it, i cant bring myself to believe it is true @azif00 unless i am not seeing how to apply this fact

Comment: The kernel is in a four dimensional space and the image is in a three dimensional space. It's impossible for them to have any vectors in common. Even the zero vector is different between the spaces.